# IIS ARR does not handle requests on port 80

Tags: iis, iis-7, arr

I have following global rule in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2

```
   <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="123" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://work-monitoring/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="work-reports.mydomain.com" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
    <proxy enabled="false" />
```

This rule handles successfully http requests to work-reports.mydomain.com on any port except 80 which results in 404 Not Found error code.

E.g. it handles http://work-reports.mydomain.com:777 but http://work-reports.mydomain.com:80 results in 404 Not Found error.

What is wrong with my IIS settings? Failed Request Tracing does not produce any logs. Windows Event logs do not contain any related info

Comment: If failed request tracing does not produce any logs, that means it is not likely to be IIS monitoring port 80. You have to find out the actual service on that port and disable it.

Comment: what is your site bindings? to enable frt you also need to check enable in frt edit site tracing [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirFf.png).

Comment: It is IIS who monitors port 80 because I have many other sites on port 80 with different hostnames which served by IIS as expected

Comment: did you try to just browse the site using this url http://work-reports.mydomain.com:80  ? does it show the content?

Comment: http://work-reports.mydomain.com:80 results in 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to define some default site with port 80 and with empty hostname like this

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
```

Comment: I request you to mark your solution as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue.